# Row Count after groupby and agg

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I'm trying to get the row count of each LoanRange, right now the dataframe displays the count for "JobsRetained". The sum amount still needs to display for JobsRetained.

```
jobsByRange_df = ppp_df.groupby(["Industry", "LoanRange"])["JobsRetained"].agg(['count', 'sum'])
jobsByRange_df
```

[This is the current DataFrame Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmQDV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want. Please, try this:

jobsByRange_df = ppp_df.groupby(["Industry", "LoanRange"]).agg(SumJobsRetained=('JobsRetained', 'sum'), CountLoanRange=('LoanRange', 'count'))

jobsByRange_df

If it doesn't work, could you please share your dataframe? It'd be helful to get a precise answer.